# Simultaneously creating messages on different queues

Tags: php, rabbitmq

I have a script which picks up messages from a queue, this does the pre-processing required for the other processes to work.

Now, these messages have to be delivered so I need to ack these messages and if one of the services listening for messages goes down then it should receive the messages it missed when it comes back online.

A couple questions:

1/ Does it make sense to have a queue for each post-processing service which is added to everytime the pre-processing runs? (So I might add to 8 different queues at the same time following each process - this will be a ton of messages (hundreds of thousands p/day).

2/ How quick is it to add messages to a queue? Is adding to 8-10 queues going to slow down my software?

3/ Can I use a topic exchange to do this with fanout? My only concern is if one of my services goes down they will miss the message.

4/ Any tips from persons with experience?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few thoughts:

If your post-processors are each doing a different 'job' then it makes sense to have queues for them to consume from. If you just have a bunch of post-processors all doing the same task, then you only need to have one queue from which they can all consume messages from.

Adding messages to queues is FAST, adding queues into RabbitMQ is fast, binding the queues to exchanges is fast. The thing that will slow down your system would be the size of the messages and the number that you are likely to receive, and then how much processing actually needs to be done.

The other consideration is to do with persistence of messages, should your messages survive a restart of RabbitMQ, that is, how critical are they? if it is critical that they not be lost (which by the sounds of your question it is) then you will need to make sure they are persisted. If you look at the RabbitMQ documentation you will see that there is a significant cost in doing this.

This depends on what your system is actually doing...Topcis are good, Fanouts are good, but what your system does depends on which is applicable.

I would *highly* recommend reading RabbitMQ in Action it is an excellent resource and well worth the money.

Comment: Hi @kzhen thanks for your response, my post processors are all doing different jobs you are correct. My pre-processing script will post to  their queues with the ID of the record in the database that needs work, it is the persistence and durability that I require. My question is more from a neatness point of view - it seems a shame to have to publish to 10 queues simultaneously with exactly the same message. It doesn't seem possible to bind more than one queue to a channel and then publish to that channel where all queues get the message (it seems publish requires a queue name?)

Comment: @williamvicary with RabbitMQ you always publish into an exchange. So with your neatness point, you will publish into an exchange and the exchange will forward your message into the queues that are bound to it. As for your question around channel bindings, this also shouldn't be applicable (perhaps you could post some of your code) as you will bind your channel to the exchange, something like $channel->exchange.declare('exchange-name', 'exchange-type', ...) then used a $channel->basic_publish('message', 'routingKey')

Comment: Looking at the PHP examples here check out "new_task.php" they don't make use of the exchange https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-tutorials/blob/master/php/new_task.php so are you saying if I declare an exchange and then declare some queues to that exchange when I publish without a queue that the exchange will send the messages to all of the queues bound to it in that session?

Comment: To clarify, if a queue isn't listening (ie one of my workers) the messages can't just be lost which was my incorrect? assumption of how exchanges work.

Comment: Take a look at https://github.com/rabbitinaction/sourcecode/blob/master/php/chapter-1/hello-world-producer.php for an example of publishing to an exchange.
As long as your queues are durable and you've set the message to be persistent ('delivery_mode' => 2) then you're messages will survive

Comment: Oh, and don't forget you will need to bind the queues to the exchange, you can do this through your php code, or just through the RabbitMQ web management. And make your exchanges durable

Comment: Thank you, I've accepted your answer, it's clarified a few things about exchanges (I wasn't aware when you published a message without an exchange it used a default exchange instead for example). Really helpful, thanks!